# Spring integration - Generic Webservice Outbound Gateway, any performance issue?

Tags: spring-integration

I have an application which connects to more than 15 SOAP services. is there any performance issue if I use a single instance of a ws outbound gateway for all the calls. The idea is to create a GENERIC SOAP Connector implementation by externalizing the ws outbout gateway configurations such as endpoint url, marshaller, unmarshaller etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no big difference, because WS Outbound Gateway is fully based on the `WebServiceTemplate` which is stateless, therefore any concurrent request doesn't impact each other.

Only might be the problem that you can't change  `marshaller`/`unmarshaller` at runtime. They are really fully tied with `WebServiceTemplate` instance.